# How to build the hello-world example of uiautomator testing framework

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

I am new to Android's uiautomator testing framework: http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_ui.html

I am trying to build the hello-world example described in section "[A sample uiautomator test case](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_ui.html#builddeploy)". When I proceed to step 3 (running "ant build"), I got following error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_55\lib\tools.jar;C:
\Users\xxx\AndroidHacker\tools\jakarta-ant-1.5.1\bin\..\lib\xml-apis.jar;C:\U
sers\xxx\AndroidHacker\tools\jakarta-ant-1.5.1\bin\..\lib\xercesImpl.jar;C:\U
sers\xxx\AndroidHacker\tools\jakarta-ant-1.5.1\bin\..\lib\optional.jar;C:\Use
rs\xxx\AndroidHacker\tools\jakarta-ant-1.5.1\bin\..\lib\ant.jar;
```

Can anyone see the problem?

Comment: Try [Uiautomator-bot](http://sourceforge.net/projects/uiautomator/). you would not have to face all this steps.

Comment: Please check the blog post written by me : http://diveshblog.com/ui-testing/android-uiautomator-getting-started/

Answer (score 1):

Jeff,

Verify if the file tools.jar exists in the path Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_55/lib/.

If it doesn't, maybe you've installed only Java JRE and then you need to download and install the JDK version. That's necessary because the JRE version doesn't contain the compiler and some libraries, like tools.jar.

Link to download JDK: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Otherwise, I would recommend you verify the enviroment varible JAVA_HOME with the following command in cmd:

```
echo %JAVA_HOME%
```

It must point to the path where your JDK is installed. In my case it's

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_60
```

In case you want to edit the path, you can use the command setx:

```
setx JAVA_HOME=Path_to_your_sdk
```

Or go to Control Panel > System and Security > System > Advanced System settings > Environment Variables, then modify the value of the variable JAVA_HOME at "User variables" to the sdk path.